# user_properties using GraphAPI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

Looks like User Properties are supported only in IOS and Android SDK
so for our canvas game I'm trying to update user properties using GraphAPI.

In Graph Api Explorer I'm trying to POST to 
`"{application-id}/user_properties"` edge.

When posting

```
data = [{"user_unique_id":"DD","custom_data":{s:1}}]
```

I get following error

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "(#100) Invalid property key in some entries: s",
>       "type": "OAuthException",
>       "code": 100,
>       "fbtrace_id": "FYce0Q+zd+d"   } }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem was related to short property name 's'. Looks like min size for user property is 2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this issue to us. User Properties support will be supported in JS SDK too in the coming months.